# mistake in @media css code. should be simple

Tags: css, mobile, width

I'm trying to use an @media command to set an element of my site to a different height for mobile browsing and i cant seem to get the code working. i would be very grateful if anyone here could see where i'm going wrong and point me in the right direction.

```
body .gilidPanel-opener {
   top: 55%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 700px){
body .gilidPanel-opener {
      top: 85%;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code there.  But if you're using top the elements need to be position:absolute

Comment: i cant set the element to absolute as it'd mess with the rest of the page's styling. is there another value i could replace 'top' with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `position` property value is `static` by default, you need to provide different value such as `absolute`, `fixed` or `relative` to make your `top` property works, so try:

```
body .gilidPanel-opener {
   position: relative; /* or absolute or fixed */
   top: 55%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 700px){
body .gilidPanel-opener {
      position: relative; /* or absolute or fixed */
      top: 85%;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply! the only value that works with the rest of the page is 'fixed' but with that the @media code still wont fire.
(www.focallocal.org - tab on the left of the screen)